# Removing Top 5% of Records

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code and I would like to remove the top 5% of the records for the `Triage_To_Dr_Sees_Adjust` numeric variable. Is this possible(I know using `Select TOP(95) Percent` would give me the top 95% but I want reverse of that, I would like the bottom 95%)?. Thank you!

UPDATE: I included code from an answer below, now my issue is that this code produces no records.

```
use EMTCQIData

DECLARE @StartDate Date
DECLARE @EndDate Date

Set @StartDate = '05/01/2017'
Set @EndDate = '12/31/2018'


SELECT sub.*
    FROM (
    Select *,
    Format([CHECKIN_DATE_TIME],'dddd') AS Checkin_Day,  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CHECKIN_DATE_TIME],111) as Checkin_date, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[CHECKIN_DATE_TIME],108) as Checkin_Time, 
    Case when TRIAGE_TO_DR_SEES < 0 then 0 else TRIAGE_TO_DR_SEES end as 
    TRIAGE_TO_DR_SEES_ADJUST 
    FROM ED_TAT_MASTER
    WHERE 
    (CHECKIN_DATE_TIME > @StartDate and CHECKIN_DATE_TIME < @EndDate) 
    AND (TRIAGE_DATE_TIME not like '')
    AND (TRIAGE_TO_DR_SEES not like '%no%')
    AND (TRACK_GROUP='ED Tracking Group') 
    AND (FORMAT([CHECKIN_DATE_TIME], 'dddd') = 'Sunday') 
    AND CHECKIN_DATE_TIME not like '%2017-07-02%' 
    AND CHECKIN_DATE_TIME not like '%2017-12-24%'
    AND CHECKIN_DATE_TIME not like '%2018-06-10%'
) sub

WHERE sub.TRIAGE_TO_DR_SEES not in (select top(5) Percent sub.TRIAGE_TO_DR_SEES
FROM ED_TAT_MASTER
ORDER BY CHECKIN_DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: Why not use `TOP (5) PERCENT` and switch the direction of your `ORDER BY`? The "last" 5 percent of records in one direction is the first in the other.

Comment: "I would like the bottom 95%"   ... the "bottom" 95% is just the top 95% in reverse order.

Comment: Personally, I would go with my answer. I feel that that `IN` could be expensive (you'll need to do 2 scans of the table), and this seems harder to read.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, apologies but I'm confused where to start in implementing your answer within my original query. This link provides some insight but I'm still having issues. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-with-clause/

Comment: What bit is it you're struggling with @Greg? The subquery or the outer query? At the end of the day, the query is simple `SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP (95) PERCENT * FROM [Table] ORDER BY ID DESC) ORDER BY ID ASC;` I don't mean to be rude, but I'm not sure what part of that is difficult to understand there.

Comment: @Larnu you are not being rude, my fault for not being clear! I was referring to your answer. I'm not sure how to use the WITH clause within my original query.

Comment: You don't need to `WITH`. That was just me generating sample data. I'll update the query a bit for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the "last" 95 percent is just the "first" 95 percent the other way, so just reverse your `ORDER BY`. If the "final" order of your data is that important, then you can wrap it in a subquery:

```
--Generate some sample data (numbers 1 to 1000)
WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))V(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2
         CROSS JOIN N N3)
--The solution
SELECT I
FROM (SELECT TOP (95) PERCENT I
      FROM Tally
      ORDER BY I DESC) T
ORDER BY I ASC;
```

This returns the numbers 51-1000 in numerical order, aka the "last" 95%.

So, for your query, in Pseudo-SQL, it'll be:

```
SELECT {YourColumns}
FROM (SELECT TOP (95) PERCENT
             {YourColumns},
             CHECKIN_DATE_TIME
      FROM ED_TAT_MASTER
      WHERE ...
      ORDER BY CHECKIN_DATE_TIME DESC --The reverse of the order you want
      ) AS T
ORDER BY CHECKIN_DATE_TIME ASC;
```

Comment: Not only is this a lot easier to understand it works in all situations.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you! This code runs but it's still returning the top 95% of my values, the variable I'm attempting to remove the top 5% of values from is `TRIAGE_TO_DR_SEES`.

Comment: Then you need to change the column in the `ORDER BY` @Greg. I can't really explain anymore than I have. If you don't understand the SQL you shouldn't be using it (it's you who needs to support it, not I or anyone else on Stack Overflow); but if you don't understand it then you need to start learning SQL. `ORDER BY` is one of the basic operators in SQL. I suggest have a google of some online tutorials or maybe signing up to a course. Good luck!

Comment: @Larnu, thanks! The data generated code removes the bottom 5% of my values (keeps top 95%).  If I have values 1-1000, I want to remove anything greater than 950. The code your provided above removed 1-50 and then flipped the order of 51-950.

Answer (score 7):

This gets the top 5 percent in a subquery, then gets everything else in the main query.  So add your logic for the 5% in the subquery, then the outer query will get you everything else.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE TableIdentity NOT IN (
    SELECT TOP (5) PERCENT TableIdentity
    FROM TableName
    ORDER BY TableIdentity (OR whatever logic you want)
)
```

Comment: thank you! For some reason, I'm having an issue embedding this code within my preexisting code as I'm not seeing any records removed. I updated my code above to reflect your answer. I suspect I'm making a stupid mistake.

Comment: Do you want your where logic applied to top 5% as well, if so need that in the subquery as well.  But main issue is you are using OR after the subquery and that is the issue.  You are saying NOT top 5% OR the other logic.  So make that AND.

Comment: I would like my preexisting WHERE logic to be applied first. Then, I would like to take out the top 5% of TRIAGE_TO_DR_SEES times. This is also something I'm struggling with. Apologies for my lack of clarity.

Comment: I am now having issues after writing the subquery-see updated question above. The subquery produces no records (I do not get an error) it's just all of the records are blank.